# PHP Unexpected 'var' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

For whatever reason, I have a small bit of PHP code that no matter where I put `var $blah;`, it always gives this error in the logs: `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR) in /path/to/file.php on line xx`

I have no idea why it wouldn't accept this. A class that is included (which creates the `$proverbSite` variable in another php section) uses plenty of 'var $blah', with no problems. I also realise this is probably just an embarassingly simple mistake.

```
<?php
        $proverbSite->dbConnect();
        $result = $proverbSite->dbQuery("randProverb");

        if($result != null) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo $row['proverb'];
            echo "<br>";
        }

?>
```

Comment: And which is `line xx` ?

Comment: Usually errors like this are due to unbalanced quotes, or a missing `;` somewhere.

Comment: look at the line preceeding xx in /path/to/file.php for something missing

Comment: Or it's due to using `var $x=1;` outside of a class declaration.

Comment: You should probably go to line xx on file.php and check for a syntax error instead of beating yourself up

Comment: possible duplicate of [T\_VAR Error with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6362098)

Comment: possible duplicate of [T\_VAR Error with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362098/t-var-error-with-php)

Comment: The code you've posted has nothing to do with the problem. Post the code that has the error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keyword `var` is only used in classes (in PHP). In the plain scope variables are automatically declared as you mention them. Just erase it, and it should work.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem. I didn't realise `var` was for classes only (this wasn't inside a class). Derp.

Answer (score 7):

Check the line before `xx` because you may have forgotten a `;` and this may cause PHP to interpret it incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing all the sources involved, I'm guessing you're combining JavaScript and PHP.

JavaScript variable declarations begin with 'var' and PHP does not...  If PHP were to encounter the code 'var' before a variable, it would give the error message you listed.  T_VAR usually indicates PHP is trying to interpret a constant, which would be the case with a JavaScript 'var'.

Now, as for the plugin/library your are using, it may be echoing javascript, but including a PHP variable, ex:

```
echo "var myJavasScriptVar = '$phpVar'";
```

In PHP, '$' in a string means that it will be replaced by a variable.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know that in newer versions of Laravel it works if you leave out the **var** keyword, for example:

```
Route::get('/read', function(){

   $results = DB::select('select * from posts where id = ?', [1]);
      return  dump($results);

});
```